# Jenkins Sonar fails on Periodic Jobs but works on manually started jobs

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonar-runner

Im using Sonar with Sonar Runner and Jenkins.
Strange thing is that when i start the job manually everything works fine but on the periodic nightly builds it fails and says:

org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: No files matching pattern "java" in directory

So i understand that Sonar Runner cant find my source files. But why is that so? I mean when i start it manually Sonar is working fine and using source files. i didn't change anything. 
Its the exact same job...

Comment: Sounds like Jenkins is running from a different directory. Are the java files located within the Jenkins project workspace?

Comment: Jenkins is downloading all java files in the project workspace folder in the Jenkins folder. Thats were im pointing at. Ok now I get the same error when i start it manually. Last week it worked.. didn't change anything... strange thing

Answer (score 0):

If I generalize your question to "What should I do if my Jenkins job fails at random times after working other times?" one of the first steps I always do is delete the workspace and rerun the build.  You can also usually configure the SCM plugin to do a clean checkout of the source rather than an update.  That has solved issues for me in the past.

Comment: Sometimes actually deleting the workspace solves weird issues for me.  It is sort of like "reboot Windows" -- a catch-all solution.  But granted I don't have a specific reason to think it will solve your issue.